# SonarScanner ignoring coverage data of Swift files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've set up a Sonar project that has development pods. The analysis works fine i.e code smells and duplications are being detected and being shown on SonarQube server but coverage data gets ignored with the log showing this:

```
INFO: Parsing /Users/daniyal/MyApp/sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml
INFO: Imported coverage data for 0 files
INFO: Coverage data ignored for 4403 unknown files, including:
/Users/daniyal/MyApp/AccountStore/AccountStore/AccountProvider.swift
```

Sonar-project.properties looks like this

```
sonar.host.url=https://*******-engineering.com/
sonar.login=**********token*********
sonar.projectKey=MyApp
sonar.projectName=MyApp
sonar.language=swift
sonar.c.file.suffixes=-
sonar.cpp.file.suffixes=-
sonar.objc.file.suffixes=-
sonar.sources=.
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
sonar.test.inclusions=*.swift
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,Pods/**/*,Reports/**/*
sonar.tests=AccountStore/AccountStoreTests
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=13.3
sonar.swift.project=MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj
sonar.swift.workspace=MyApp.xcworkspace
sonar.swift.appName=MyApp
sonar.swift.appScheme=MyAppScheme
sonar.swift.appConfiguration=Debug
sonar.coverageReportPaths=sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml
```

Excerpt from sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml

```
<coverage version="1">
  <file path="/Users/daniyal/MyApp/AccountStore/AccountStore/AccountProvider.swift">
    <lineToCover lineNumber="27" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="28" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="29" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="30" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="31" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="33" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="34" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="35" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="38" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="39" covered="true"/>
  </file>
</coverage>
```

Comment: Has your `sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml` been generated and includes the expected information? there is usually a step that you run a sh script after the test suite finishes to convert the xccovreport to this generic format

Comment: Yes `sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml` is generated as expected. Added an excerpt of it in question

Comment: its probably becuase its not using relative paths, not sure how to get around that one tbh. i'll have a look. Im in the middle of setting this up myself so if i find anything i'll let you know

Comment: @DaniyalRaza Did you get solution for your issue, Even I am facing same issue from past 5 days, If you have fixed that, Can you please put your answer here, It would be helpful to me. Really appreciate your kind help

Comment: @DaniyalRaza: Did you got solution to your problem?: